# Amazon lightsail distribution timeout

Tags: timeout, amazon-lightsail

We're running wordpress on lightsail (with a CDN/distribution) and occasionally things take longer than 30 seconds and we get 504 errors.

It seems out lightsail distribution times out after 30 seconds. I know in cloudfront you can configure this, but can't seem to find a setting in the UI or CLI. Does anyone know if its possible?

thanks,

Max

Comment: I couldn't figure this out. I ended up solving it by increasing the RAM in a lightsail database and avoiding the timeouts in the first place.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you have any 504 errors after increasing the RAM?

Comment: No all the errors have gone and the site is lightning fast. The errors were caused by the database queries taking longer than 30 seconds, which happened often in the wordpress admin backend, and occasionally in the front end.

Comment: Thank you for answering. In the meantime I've upgraded my instance as well, and so far so good. Fingers crossed this was the fix